# Combine 2 Queries using Union with difference column

Tags: mysql

I have 2 Queries. I need to combine it to get actual result.
Here is Query 1 :

```
SELECT a.city as c1, 
sum(c.gps_exam1) as c2, 
sum(c.gps_exam2) as c3, 
sum(c.avg_exam1) as c4, 
sum(c.avg_exam2) as c5,
count(c.gps_exam1) as c6, 
count(c.gps_exam2) as c7, 
count(c.avg_exam2) as c8, 
count(c.avg_exam2) as c9,
from report_sekolah a 
join report_stu b 
on a.uid=b.uid 
join report_exam c 
on b.uid=c.uid 
group by a.city
```

Here is Query 2 :

```
SELECT sum(b.stu_bil) as c10 
from   report_sekolah a 
join   report_stu b 
  on   a.uid=b.uid 
group by a.city
```

I need to combine it to get actual result. What I have done is by using union. Here is the query :

```
SELECT a.city as c1, 
       sum(c.gps_exam1) as c2, 
       sum(c.gps_exam2) as c3, 
       sum(c.avg_exam1) as c4, 
       sum(c.avg_exam2) as c5, 
       count(c.gps_exam1) as c6, 
       count(c.gps_exam2) as c7, 
       count(c.avg_exam2) as c8, 
       count(c.avg_exam2) as c9, 
       null as c10 
from   report_sekolah a 
join   report_stu b 
  on   a.uid=b.uid 
join   report_exam c 
  on   b.uid=c.uid 
group by a.city 
UNION ALL 
SELECT null as c1, 
       null as c2,  
       null as c3, 
       null as c4, 
       null as c5,  
       null as c6, 
       null as c7, 
       null as c8, 
       null as c9, 
       sum(b.stu_bil) as c10 
from   report_sekolah a 
join   report_stu b 
  on   a.uid=b.uid 
group by a.city
```

But it give wrong row result. then I try to use query below, but wrong result for total students.

```
SELECT a.city as c1, 
sum(c.gps_exam1) as c2, 
sum(c.gps_exam2) as c3, 
sum(c.avg_exam1) as c4, 
sum(c.avg_exam2) as c5,
count(c.gps_exam1) as c6, 
count(c.gps_exam2) as c7, 
count(c.avg_exam2) as c8, 
count(c.avg_exam2) as c9, 
sum(b.stu_bil) as c10
from report_sekolah a 
join report_stu b 
on a.uid=b.uid 
join report_exam c 
on b.uid=c.uid
group by a.city
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to change the one field (c10) value to set the SubQuery.

```
SELECT a.city as c1, 
sum(c.gps_exam1) as c2, 
sum(c.gps_exam2) as c3, 
sum(c.avg_exam1) as c4, 
sum(c.avg_exam2) as c5,
count(c.gps_exam1) as c6, 
count(c.gps_exam2) as c7, 
count(c.avg_exam2) as c8, 
count(c.avg_exam2) as c9, 
(SELECT sum(stu_bil) From report_stu Where a.uid=uid) as c10
from report_sekolah a 
join report_stu b 
on a.uid=b.uid 
join report_exam c 
on b.uid=c.uid
group by a.city
```

Comment: the first row is correct. and next row is wrong. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT y.c1, y.c2, y.c3, y.c4, y.c5, y.c6, y.c7, y.c8, y.c9 , z.result
FROM
(
SELECT a.city as c1, 
sum(c.gps_exam1) as c2, 
sum(c.gps_exam2) as c3, 
sum(c.avg_exam1) as c4, 
sum(c.avg_exam2) as c5,
count(c.gps_exam1) as c6, 
count(c.gps_exam2) as c7, 
count(c.avg_exam2) as c8, 
count(c.avg_exam2) as c9,
    a.uid
from report_sekolah a 
join report_stu b 
on a.uid=b.uid 
join report_exam c 
on b.uid=c.uid GROUP BY a.city
) y
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT sum(b.stu_bil) as result,
    b.uid
    from report_sekolah a join report_stu b on a.uid=b.uid group by a.city
) z
ON y.uid = z.uid
```